# How can I stringify output from a for loop?

Tags: javascript, query-string

I have the following for loop and I would like the output of the loop to be stringified into a query string as shown in the desired output below. I'm using the [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) npm package for stringifying URLs.

What's the best way of going about getting the desired output?

```
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) { 
      var foo =  "pr" + [i] + "va";
      var bar = "value";
  };
  //Desired output: ?pr0va=value&pr1va=value
```

Comment: can You rephrase question? I think we all misunderstand it because of code snippet. If You want to use qs package then please show as what data You have, if You want to just create string then You do not need any qs lib for that and our answers are correct. Qs if for convertig data structures to query, and I don't see any data structure, creating it here to create query has small sense and the same would be just create string query like in answers.

Comment: @MaciejSikora I have a JSON response that looks like the following below. I have a couple products that I'm pulling from an API, so I want to loop through them to pull the values and put them into a query string.

    "itemizations":[  
      {  
         "name":"T-Shirt",
         "quantity":"1.00000000",
         "notes":"Regular T-shirt",
         "item_variation_name":"White"
}
      {  
         "name":"T-Shirt",
         "quantity":"1.00000000",
         "notes":"Regular T-shirt",
         "item_variation_name":"White"
}
]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating variables - create String and do concatenation in every loop.

Check my code snippet.

```js
   var query = "";
   var size = 2;

   for (i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
      query +=  "pr" + [i] + "va=value";
      
      if (i+1<size)
        query += "&";
   };

   console.log(query);
```

Comment: @iabramo No problem!

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
function test () {
  var i =0;
  var arr = [];
    for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
     arr.push( "pr" + [i] + "va=value" );
  }
  console.log('?' + arr.join('&').toString())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
  var output = '?';

  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) { 
      var foo =  "pr" + [i] + "va";
      var bar = "value";
      output += foo + "=" + bar + "&";
  };

  console.log(output);

  //Desired output: ?pr0va=value&pr1va=value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```js
var output = "?";
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) { 
  output += "pr" + [i] + "va=value&";
};
console.log(output.slice(0, -1))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were to review such code I would prefer to see the following:

- Avoid concatenation.
- Use of functional programming.
- Reasonable usage of 3rd parties - so yes for `querystring`

All of those are for readability, simplicity and maintainability benefits. And I admit it is arguable.. so please don't argue :)

I will use your code as a baseline and improve from there

```
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) { 
      var foo =  "pr" + [i] + "va";
      var bar = "value";
  };
```

Note that your snippet is incomplete, and so, at the beginning mine will not be complete too, but I'll get there

## Avoid concatenation

I will avoid concatenation using template literal

```
 for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) { 
     `pr${i}va=value`;
 };
```

## Use of functional programming

I will iterate over numbers using an array, and reduce to construct an object

```
 const queryParams = Array(2).fill().reduce((object, value, index) => {
          object[`pr${index}va`] = 'value';
          return object;
      } , {} )
```

## Using 3rd parties

Now I will use `querystring` to turn `queryParams` to a query string

```
 return querystring.stringify(queryParams);
```

## All together now

```
 /**
  * @param {number} count - number of query parameters to generate
  * @returns {string} query string. for example for count=2 will return `pr1va=value&pr2va=value`
  **/
 function generateQueryString(count=2){
     const queryParams = Array(count).fill().reduce((object, value, index) => { // convert N number to key-value map using reduce
          object[`pr${index}va`] = 'value';
          return object;
      } , {} );
      return querystring.stringify(queryParams);         
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of size, loop and then join it:

```js
function createString(size) {
  return new Array(size).fill(0).map((v, i) => {
   return "pr" + i + "va=value";
  }).join("&");
}

console.log(createString(2));
```